# Finding matrix $B$

Tags: matrices

Any suggestions at to what matrix $B$ is such that$\|X[(I+YX)^{-1}-I]-BY\|=O(\|Y^a\|)$ where $a>1$ and $X,Y,B$ are all square matrices of the same size and $I$ is the identity matrix and $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm?

Also, to be clear $O(\cdot)$ is the [big-$O$ notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) .

Thank you.

Comment: What does big-O mean for matrix-valued functions?